# Can’t start DHCP server in whonix gateway. Help please!

Tags: configuration

I want to use a android VM linked to a whonix gateway. I followed the tutorial as described here:
https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Other_Operating_Systems#Whonix-Android-Workstation
The installing and changing dhcpd.conf goes fine (I think), and I double checked the dhcpd.conf too.

When I run ''sudo dpkg-reconfigure isc-dhcp-server'' I can set the interface to eth1, but after that I get this:
''Job for isc-dhcp-server.service failed. See 'systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript isc-dhcp-server, action ''start'' failed.''

I tried in several versions of the gateway. I suspect doing something wrong in the dhcpd.conf file, I deleted everything that was in it and replaced with this:

option domain-name "whonix";
option domain-name-servers 10.152.152.10;
subnet 10.152.128.0 netmask 255.255.192.0 {
        range 10.152.152.12 10.152.152.15;
        option subnet-mask 255.255.192.0;
        option broadcast-address 10.152.191.255;
        option routers 10.152.152.10;
}
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

Please help since I have been looking online for solution for hours now..

thanks in advance